Do airports conduct drug tests when you arrive from another country?
I have had marijuana in the last 3 months, and am now planning a Europe trip. I am not taking any drugs with me.
It is my first time travelling to another country so I am now feeling paranoid that I’ll get drug tested and they’ll find that I’m positive.
My brother told me he got a random drug test done in Greece, so now feeling paranoid.
I’m thinking of going to

United Kingdom
Spain
Switzerland
Germany
Italy
Iceland
Turkey

Any thoughts? Why would they drug test passengers? What happens if it is positive? I know this is probably a dumb question but I am feeling very paranoid so would appreciate if someone could provide some guidance or advice.

If anyone conducts a drug test, it's not likely to be the airport but rather the customs service, immigration service, or some other law enforcement agency of the national or local government.

Are you sure your brother did not experience a residue swab test and is just calling that a ‘drug test’? I’ve run into this myself multiple times at ATH when traveling for work, albeit usually when going through airport security on the way out, not when entering the country. Such tests can be done to check for narcotics, precursor chemicals, explosives, gunshot residue, and any number of other things and are generally not an issue unless you are carrying/wearing anything that would test positive.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Airports don't test for drugs. Law enforcement may be able to compel a test on you, but in democratic countries this is not done "at random". Only if there's a suspicion that you're doing something you're not allowed to do when under the influence (driving, for example). Your belongings may be searched at the airport, at random, by the customs or security personnel. So don't bring any drugs with you.
Generally, traveling under the influence (even of illicit drugs) is not illegal unless you become disruptive or unruly.
It is more likely that your brother is trolling you than that he got "a random test in Greece".

While it makes sense, really need to verify the "Airports don't test for drug" claim.

@ShadowWizard it’s proverbially difficult to prove a negative, but no, “airports” don’t test for drugs. Law enforcement such as immigration, customs or police officers may do it inside an airport, but it’s not the airport doing that.

Maybe the brother is referencing those baggage and clothing swab tests? Those are at random at airports for drugs as far as I know?

@DavidMulder I always thought those are for explosives, not drugs.

I'm not sure it's helpful to differentiate between "the airport" and "the police, customs and other officials at the airport". It makes no difference to the traveller exactly who is doing what and it makes the answer confusing to read. Clearly the building doesn't test for drugs (nor it's owners) but colloquially the whole thing is called "the airport"

@RichardTingle why are you trying to use common sense on SE? But in all seriousness I'm sure OP is fine if they are jailed by the officers and not the airport janitor.

@RichardTingle it actually does. It does make a difference who, it does make a difference why, in some countries that's the difference between life in prison and a hefty compensation from the other side for the inconvenience. In any case, nowhere in Europe have I heard of forced drug tests at random by any kind of law enforcement, including Greece (been there too). Bag searches? Sure, everywhere. Intrusive body search at random for no reason? Not really.

Do not help other travelers with 'luggage problems' nor briefly met acquaintances wanting gifts taken to your further destinations.

in the USA, the courts have often granted customs more leeway on ignoring the traveler's (especially foreigners) constitutional rights.

Foreigners have no constitutional rights. Admittance into the US is a privilege. That said, violating bodily autonomy is never a condition of admittance anywhere I know of.

@littleadv: They may not have a right to entry, but they definitely have constitutional rights. These are not reserved to citizens but apply to all people the government interacts with within its jurisdiction/borders.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE as suggested in another comment - no, they don't. At least not in a sense you think. There's a reason immigration proceedings are considered administrative and not judicial.

@littleadv: That doesn't contradict what I said. While there is no right to entry, there are all of the constitutional rights like due process to be convicted of a crime (distinct from being denied entry!), etc.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE tell that to all the folks at gitmo. Common, I know Americans are very proud of their constitutional rights, but you got to know that they mean nothing when it comes to people Americans don't like.

@ShadowWizard customs and border security are the ones who'd do the testing, or airport police, and those aren't the airport themselves. They're 3rd parties operating at and in conjunction with the airport staff. Airport staff will of course alert them to suspicious persons and items.

I agree with @RichardTingle, this answer is confusing, as I don't care, as a passenger, who performs the test and/or arrests me. Saying "Airports don't test for drugs" is misleading and confusing.

@littleadv: I'm not claiming our government follows its own laws, just that, according to the law, these rights are not limited to citizens.

The word "drug test" means different things at different times. It might mean:

testing your blood, breath, or the like to see if you are under the influence right now
testing your hair or urine to see if you have used recently
testing your possessions and person (eg swabbing your hands and bag) for residues
testing mysterious bags of powder found in your bag to see what you're smuggling

All of these could be called "a random test" and it's clear you're worried about the second one, but it's the least likely of the bunch. The first and third are generally done to have a reason to search your bags super thoroughly. You might be chosen randomly, or because of the origin of your flight, or the clothes you're wearing, or for some other reason that makes sense to the person choosing even if not to anyone else. Then they screen a little further (literally just smell you, maybe ask you some things) and possibly start in on a thorough search if they are suspicious. But being searched isn't the same as being sent home or being arrested.
An aside: these tests may be done at the airport but they are not done by the airport, rather by border officers employed by the country you are entering. Security does some hand-and-bag swabbing too, but that is for explosives, not drugs.
If you are not smuggling (and half a forgotten joint in a jacket pocket in your suitcase might be considered smuggling in some cases) then these tests should not worry you. I watch Border Security and people can smell like pot, can have pot paraphernalia with them, can tell the officers they smoked an hour ago, and are still let in with minimal delay. As long as they are not bringing any. (It being an accident and you not meaning to are not accepted, you have to truly truly not be bringing any.)
Only one place in the world does blood tests to check for prior use: Singapore. And they don't test visitors, only citizens and permanent residents who are returning. Further, they warn about it:

(From https://www.channelnewsasia.com/singapore/changi-airport-drug-check-enforcement-traveller-thailand-cannabis-2957591 which has more details.)
Bottom line: don't bring any pot across borders, or any cannabis related products like edibles. While there is a small chance some sort of testing will occur (someone smelling you, or swabbing something), it will not be intrusive and the strongest consequence these tests can have is a thorough search. The search may delay you, embarrass you, worry you and those waiting for you, but if you do not have any cannabis with you, that is all that will happen. The search will come up empty and you will be on your way, with a story to tell about "that time I got randomly tested in [country]".

"swabbing your hands and bag for residues" => I can confirm that at least the machines checking people's swabs post-security do not detect traces of marijuana. Too many people use it for this to make sense.

security is not swabbing for drugs. There are different machines in "secondary" (the part of border control you might go to for more processing), which most people never see.

Thanks, this answer makes much more sense than the others.

About Singapore, see travel.state.gov:

Singaporean authorities may conduct unannounced drug tests and property searches, including upon entry into the country, on foreign citizens who are suspected of consuming or possessing illegal drugs.


The "suspected of" means it won't be really random but rather in response to suspicious behavior or when you look drugged, so as long as one behaves normally they have nothing to worry about, I think.

Can downvoters explain?

And if you are a Singapore citizen or PR, you can be charged with drug use and arrested, even if you consumed it overseas.

The OP is not asking about Singapore.

@littleadv it's still variable to put things into a broader perspective. Wouldn't want someone to get executed because they thought Singapore is in Europe ;)

@ShadowWizard true but OP is "feeling very paranoid", which may arise suspicion :)

@DonQuiKong also it's well-known that all flights are non-stop flights.

See Kate's answer which expands on this, and also clarifies why what you're claiming is wrong. Even if the OP was going to Singapore - Singapore has no jurisdiction over them until they arrive, and testing for something that happened in the past makes no sense. Drug consumption is illegal in Singapore, so Singaporeans traveling abroad (being Singaporeans they still under Singapore jurisdiction) may be tested. Them (also) being foreign citizens is meaningless to this point.

According to this article, in Greece possession of even small quantities of drugs can lead to lengthy (up to and including your entire life span) imprisonment, so perhaps they random test more arrivals than elsewhere. Spain and Italy are listed as having harsh sentences.
Apart from the obvious (don’t bring any drugs with you), if you’ve taken marijuana in the past, make sure your luggage and belongings/clothes don’t contain any minute trace from previous use that sniffer dogs might pick up on. Also check that any travelling companion(s) are not carrying any drugs.
As others have commented, the minimum repercussion of testing positive would likely be denial of entry and an unexpectedly swift trip back to your home country at your own expense.

The question is NOT about possession, it's a about detection of past drug use.

@Hilmar Part of the question is why would they drug test passengers. I’ve seen episodes of eg Australian Border Force where residual traces of past drug use in luggage get the traveller flagged for questioning/testing.

I wonder about the "minute trace" thing.  Drug use is fairly ubiquitous in much of the world (notably by politicians and members of law enforcement!).  When you throw your bags in a chair/cab/taxi/bus/Uber/Lyft/rickshaw/tuk-tuk/boat/rental car/train/airplane/whatever, guess what, it comes in contact with surfaces used by hundreds/thousands of drug users and their luggage.  I'm guessing, by now, almost every human in every major city has minute traces of drugs on them, their clothing, and their luggage.

While I agree on the various answers already given special consideration must be made for Iceland.
If you arrive in Reykjavik from Europe, especially on a flight coming from Amsterdam, there is a VERY high chance you will be sniffed by a narcotics dog. It is almost standard procedure in Iceland.
The dog may pick up on substances that you handled several days before your travel. Even stuff transferred from another person you shook hands with several days before the travel.
Especially cannabis is notorious for having a lingering smell that humans can't smell (unless it is really fresh/strong), but the dog can still smell it days later.
As long as you're not carrying anything on your person or in your luggage you will be fine, but you can be held several hours at the airport before they release you.
I have travelled to Iceland about a dozen times (work related) and I got the sniff-test on all but one occasion. Was detained 3 times. Even though I don't use any recreational substances myself.
1 time because of transfer from the guy sitting next to me on the plane. (His clothing reeked of pot, I could smell it myself on the plane.)
Both other times I had no idea how or when I had come in contact with any illicit substance.
But anyway after some questioning and a thorough examination of my luggage, which turned up nothing, I could go after 2 or 3 hours.

germany has legalised Cannabis, although tourists must not buy it.
Drug consumption is not illegal anyways in Germany (only posession). As other answers have stated, it would still be illegal to drive, operate heavy machinery, etc. under the influence. But since your last use was 3 monthes ago, you should be fine.

The Wikipedia text, in the english version, is a bit misleading. At present nobody can buy it. Legal residents of Germany can grow a certain amount in their home or as a member of a club.
